# Jplayer Circle Player not playing mp3 file

Tags: mp3, jplayer

I've just downloaded the jplayer circle player and it works great. However when I change the link to my own mp3 file it stops working. Is there something else I should be doing? Thanks

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
        {
            /*These work fine when not commented out
            m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
            oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg",*/
            mp3: "myfolder/mytrack.mp3", //This doesn't work!
        }
```

Comment: Solved it: There's a "supplied" option in the javascript and I need to specify I'm supplying an mp3 as well as the m4a and oga (which were already in the code).

Comment: I have the same problem, I specified mp3 in 'supplied' but it only works in chrome... any suggestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The response from @mgraph is basically "hacking core." If you update circle.player.js, you'll have to remember to re-apply the modification. All that's defined in that file is defaults. It would probably be better to modify the invocation code.

In the circle player demo file(currently `demo-05.htm`), find the options block, which currently looks like:

```
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
```

and add your own value for the [supplied](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-supplied) parameter, eg.

```
    supplied: "mp3",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js",
    wmode: "window"
```

...which will then override the value set in circle.player.js