# Why won't Jplayer CirclePlayer play mp3, the other Jplayer skins all do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fairly new to coding (playing with html5 Ccs3 and JavaScript for about 2 mths now) and I'm trying to get the Jplayer CirclePlayer to play mp3 format using their demo file "demo-05.htm".

Here's the snipit of code in that I've altered per information I've found here in other posts, but I still can't make CirclePlayer work in either IE10 or current release Google Chrome, though other Jplayer skins play the mp3's.

I've added the error alerts but received none on last try.

If someone can help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it, as I'm really new to this coding stuff and I keep coming up against strange anomalies.

If I can get this to work, then I need to figure out how to use the CirclePlayer to play multiple mp3 files on the same page!

Here's the code I've been working with so far. All the media files are at the same folder level as the htm file, the JS JS and Skin folders are at the same level as the htm file as I'm working out of the demo folder while testing the player.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(document).ready(function(){

var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
mp3: "001.mp3"
m4a: "Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
oga: "Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
}, {
supplied: "mp3", "m4a", "oga",
cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
swfPath: "js",
wmode: "window",
keyEnabled: true
errorAlerts: true,
warningAlerts: true
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch for whatever assistance you can offer to a newbie!

iamjoedy

Comment: Can you update this with what the error is or does it just not work? Not clear from your post. Have you traced this through a JavaScript debugger to take a look at what it is doing? Also it would be helpful for format your JavaScript so it is easier to read.

Comment: "Thanks for the reply" continued

"Comments May only be edited for 5 minutes!"
 
How can I reply in a 3/4" window with a built in character limitation that wants me to use non-existent format controls?

Now I need to learn how to ask and answer questions too! 

My frustration level is climbing!

continued in next...

Comment: "Thanks for the reply" continued

Since this is my first query, I had difficulties just getting the java script code into the question through the text area input, sorry I'll get better in time.

I received no error messages in either browser after adding the additional error codes.

I have not traced it through a JavaScript debugger, as I haven't learned how to use one yet!

continued in next...

Comment: "Thanks for the reply" continued

I found another post regarding CirclePlayer here "Q: jPlayer CirclePlayer Multiple Instances"  by "hendos43" in which I found a link to a website "ovalbenchmark.webs.com" where he seemed to have solved my problem, but... his page will not play in my Windows 7 PC in either IE10 or current ver Chrome, which leaves me wondering what the heck is going on ????

Does his page play on your machine? In what browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the Jplayer CirclePlayer play mp3's by following the advice of
Su found in his answer to the following question, and taking out all the additional lines of code I had previously added in an attempt to make the player work.

[jplayer-circle-player-not-playing-mp3-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555334/jplayer-circle-player-not-playing-mp3-file)
    
    //

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
    var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
    {
        mp3: "001.mp3"
    }, {
            supplied: "mp3",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
            swfPath: "js",
            wmode: "window"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

---

```
    I removed the m4a: and oga: lines
    I removed the keyEnabled: line
    I removed the errorAlerts: line
    I removed the warningAlerts: line
```

and the CirclePlayer played audios in both IE 10 and Chrome.